# Input element width is shorter than select element width

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the width of the select element is shorter than the width of the input element, I set both of them to be 100%, but it seems that the input overlays the grid boundaries for some reason.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gridView">
  <input type="text"   placeholder="Name" />
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" />
  <select></select>
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Birth Date" />
  <select> </select>
  <select> </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Passport Number" />
  <span>
  <input  placeholder="Passport Expiry Date"/>
  <span class="dateFormat">YYYY-MM-DD</span>
  </span>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 25px;
}
select {
  height: 41px;
  width:100%;
}
.gridView {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.dateFormat {
  color: red;
  font-size: small;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/AlexLavriv/oxmq71sn/1/

Comment: Your fiddle is not the same as the source here; it doesn't set the `select` widths for example.

Comment: Add: * {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have additional padding applied for `input`, but not for `select`. To get them to equal width you need to update size calculation method:

```
input, select {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you padding to padding-top and padding-bottom. you are putting 6 px all around the input which makes your input larger. in order to stop the shift we take the padding away from right and left. In essence you are saying make the input 100%+6px+6px so your result is larger than the 100% set for select.

```
input {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Padding may be part of required visual appearance. Reason of the problem is incorrect size calculation due to `box-sizing`

Comment: The size calculation is off because of the padding ive added to the answer above hope it helps

Comment: You've removed horizontal padding from input, but you don't know if it should stay or not. So your solution is limited to just some particular scenarios.

Comment: Explain please this works for all scenarios as far as i can see?  can you give me an example?

Comment: Of course. Imagine that you have to preserve these horizontal paddings (e.g. due to design requirements). In this case your proposed solution to remove them will break project requirements. It means that your solution is not applicable for every case, but just for some particular ones. Root reason of size difference is not into padding itself, but in a way browser calculates element sizes. And it is controlled by [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) style that defaults to `content-box` and not counts paddings which leads to the problem.

Comment: But if it just doesn't count paddings wouldn't my solution work just as well with less code doesn't matter about the specs of padding if you are going to omit them anyway i still get to keep top and bot padding.  I respect your answer but i find redundancy by placing a code like padding and not using it.   I think both are doing the same thing but mine as less code and calculation involved to do the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solved [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0cnb9t6/)

```css
.registerForm {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
    height: 25px;
}

  

select {
    height: 41px;
     width: 110%;
}
.gridView {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 25px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
.dateFormat {
    color: red;
    font-size: small;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="registerForm">
   <div class="gridView">
      <input type="text"   placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" />
      <select></select>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Birth Date" />
      <select> </select>
      <select> </select>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Passport Number" />
      <span>
      <input  placeholder="Passport Expiry Date"/>
      <span class="dateFormat">YYYY-MM-DD</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Actually the select width is by default 10% lesser to its input cousin..
in your case a

> style="width:110%;

is full filling the gap

```
<div class="registerForm">
   <div class="gridView">
      <input type="text"   placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" />
      <select   style="width:110%;"></select>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Birth Date" />
      <select   style="width:110%;"> </select>
      <select   style="width:110%;"> </select>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Passport Number" />
      <span>
      <input  placeholder="Passport Expiry Date"/>
      <span class="dateFormat">YYYY-MM-DD</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some sources for this statement?

Comment: Your proposal is incorrect because reason of the gap is different so update of the style will break your solution

Comment: @NAVINROY Despite your rude words you're wrong into your assumptions. How did you calculate that 12px difference is equal to 10%? What will be if container will be wider / narrower?

Comment: @AlexLavriv here is the solved [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0cnb9t6/)